# Throttled Queue Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue

I have a function `doWork(id)` that I'm offloading to some worker servers using AWS SQS. This function can get called very frequently but I'd like to throttle the function so that for a given id, the work is don't no more than once per second.

Is it possible with AWS / are there any services that feature this functionality?

---

EDIT: Some clarification.

`doWork(id)` does some expensive work on a record in a database. This work needs to continuously update whenever the user interacts with the record. Thus, I call `doWork(id)` whenever the user called a method that edits the record. However, the user may edit the record many times very quickly (I'm building a text editor so every character is an edit). Rather than `doWork(id)` a unnecessary amount of times, I'd like to throttle that work so it happens at most once per second.

Because this work is expensive, I enqueue a message in SQS and have a set of "worker" servers that dequeue tasks and run them.

My goal here is to somehow maintain the stateless horizontal scalability of my servers while throttling `doWork(id)`. To make matters a little more complicated, I don't want to throttle the `doWork` function itself -- I want to throttle the work for each individual record identified by the id passed to `doWork`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your explanation isn't very clear. Can you Edit your question to clarify the relationship between DoWork, SQS and your workers? Anyway, regardless of this, there is no feature in SQS that will vary based on the content of the message. It is simple "store message(s), retrieve message(s)".

Comment: Oh @JohnRotenstein, did that clarify? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Redis instance on ElastiCache and configure your workers to use a [distributed rate limiter](https://redis.io/commands/incr#pattern-rate-limiter-2) for keys based on `id`. There are also many packages for different languages based on this kind of idea that might be ready to run on your workers.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. You want to delay the work in case they hit another key within a given time period. If they don't hit another key in that time period, you then want to do the work. You might also want to do it after x seconds even if they continue typing (Auto Save).

The problem is that each keypress sends a message to the queue. When a worker receives the message, they have no idea whether another key has been pressed since the message was sent, and there's no way to look in the queue for other matching messages.

**Amazon SQS does have the ability to delay a message**, which means it will not be available for receiving for a given period, but this alone can't solve the problem because the worker doesn't know what else has happened.

**Bottom line:** A traditional queue is not a suitable mechanism for this use-case. You need something akin to a database/cache that can update a "last modified" timestamp each time that a key is pressed. Once that timestamp is more than *x* seconds old, you should queue the worker.